# how to make the color in ggplot more detailed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this

```
df <-structure(list(team_3_F = c("team ", "team ", "site", "site", 
"team ", "team ", "newyorkish", "newyorkish", "team ", "team ", 
"newyorkish", "newyorkish", "browingal ", "browingal ", "site", 
"site", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", 
"team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "team ", "team ", "site", "site", "browingal ", "browingal ", 
"browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", 
"browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "team ", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "newyorkish", "newyorkish", "browingal ", "browingal ", 
"newyorkish", "newyorkish", "browingal ", "browingal ", "team ", 
"team ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "team "), name = c("AAA_US", 
"BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", 
"AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", 
"BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", 
"AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", 
"BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", 
"AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", 
"BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", 
"AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", 
"BBB_US", "AAA_US"), value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 88L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 19L)), row.names = c(NA, -59L), class = "data.frame")
```

I plot it like this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = team_3_F, y = name, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile()+
  theme_classic(base_size = 12)+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red",mid = "white",midpoint = 1)
```

I want to know if there is any other way to plot it so that I dont miss the small values because I have so many zero in the data

for instance, is there a possibility to plot as points instead of block of color ? for instance in the team , putting 6 points because 6 values exists for this category

if we look below

in team category , AAA_US has 6 values meaning 6 dots
in team category , BBB_US has 0 values meaning 0 dots

```
team    AAA_US  0
team    AAA_US  1
team    AAA_US  0
team    AAA_US  0
team    AAA_US  45
team    AAA_US  0
team    AAA_US  18
team    AAA_US  0
team    AAA_US  1
team    AAA_US  4
team    AAA_US  0
team    AAA_US  19
team    BBB_US  0
team    BBB_US  0
team    BBB_US  0
team    BBB_US  0
team    BBB_US  0
team    BBB_US  0
team    BBB_US  0
team    BBB_US  0
team    BBB_US  0
team    BBB_US  0
team    BBB_US  0
```

Comment: Are you asking for general data visualization advice? Or is this a specific programming question? If you want to talk generally about plotting colors, that's off-topic for Stack Overflow and might be a better fit for [stats.se]. We can't tell you what's appropriate for your data. But if you know what you want to do but just don't know how, then that's a specific question that might fit here. Just be clear on what the specific desired behavior is.

Comment: @MrFlick
I tried to use breaks in the discrimination for plot but I could not figure how to make the color more pronounced for small values too, I have example data, I have example of plotting and I have given the question, now let me know if something is missing

Comment: What does a "more pronounced" color mean exactly? Do you not want your scale to go to white? We can't really make up more colors between red and white. Do you want to log scale the values? It's not clear what your desired result will look like.

Comment: @MrFlick
I just modified my question, is this clear now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want finer-grained differentiation between colors in the lower part of the scale. You can do this using `scale_fill_gradientn`. However, note that you also have the problem that some tiles have the same x, y co-ordinates and are therefore being drawn over earlier tiles. My guess is that you should average the values to plot them properly. I would also suggest, given that a fine-grained legend is hard to read, that you add text values to represent the values at each tile:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = team_3_F, y = name)) +
    stat_summary_2d(
    aes(z = value, fill = after_stat(value)),
    fun = mean,
    geom = "tile"
  ) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 12)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = viridis::plasma(length(unique(df$value))),
                       values = sort(unique(df$value))/max(df$value)) +
    stat_summary_2d(
    aes(z = value, 
        label = after_stat(scales::number(value, accuracy = 0.01))),
    fun = mean, color = "white", size = 8,
    geom = "text"
  ) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

If you want the color to reflect the number of non-zero counts, and want some dots to represent the non-zero counts instead of numbers, you can do:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = team_3_F, y = name)) +
    stat_summary_2d(
    aes(z = value, fill = after_stat(value)),
    fun = function(x) sum(x != 0),
    geom = "tile"
  ) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 12) +
  geom_point(data = df[df$value != 0,], color = "white", fill = "black",
             shape = 21, size = 3,
             position = position_dodge2(width = 1)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue3", mid = "white", high = "red3",
                       midpoint = 3.5) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

And if you want the numbers rather than the dots (since they look better IMO)

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = team_3_F, y = name)) +
    stat_summary_2d(
    aes(z = value, fill = after_stat(value)),
    fun = function(x) sum(x != 0),
    geom = "tile"
  ) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 12) +
  geom_label(data = df[df$value != 0,], color = "black", size = 8,
            stat = StatBin2d, aes(label = ..count..),
            fill = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue3", mid = "white", high = "red3",
                       midpoint = 3.5) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, it is for sure a better representation however, would it be possible to add number of dots in each section or not normalize it rather than normalization?

Comment: Very nice. I like it!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not normalise" it nik. It's not normalised at the moment. You want tiles with dots over them? How many dots? Where does the number of dots come in? Do you not want tiles? This almost sounds like a different question now.

Comment: @Allan Cameron
for instance look at team , you have 7.33 and 0 for AAA_US and BBB_US respectively. if you look at the question, I mentioned that for this we have 6 values only for AAA_US and 0 values for BBB_US. can you we somehow count the values and represent it as dot?

Comment: @nik but what do you want to do with the values themselves? You are talking about the number of non-zero values. Are you only interested in the count of non-zero values, but not the actual value itself?

Comment: @Allan Cameron
that is right , I dont want to do anything with the values themselves but only non-zero count

Comment: @nik see my update

Comment: @Allan Cameron
I accepted and liked your answer, thank you I have one question, is there possible to not have the dots in a line rather filling up the space ?

Comment: @nik it's _possible_ to do it, but it would be pretty involved - essentially creating a little data frame with x, y positions for all the dots. There'sno easy way to do it within the ggplot framework